# Creating WYSIWYG form builder (á la Wufoo) in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webforms, wysiwyg, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I have to add Wufoo-like WYSIWYG form-builder functionality to a Rails webapp.

Does anyone know of good resources (gems/engines/plugins/example code) that would help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is not really an answer to your question, but I still can't add comments unfortunately, due to my reputation level, sorry :)

There is exact equivalent of such functionality in Drupal(php)
http://drupal.org/project/webform especially useful for contact forms, i.e. clients happy and don't bug me every time they want to adjust or even to add new inquiry form :)

Would be nice to have such gem/plugin if any? :P

Thanks.

Comment: Interesting, I'll have to check it out. Maybe someone could work on porting that to Rails…

Comment: NYT did it [Building a Better Submission Form](http://open.blogs.nytimes.com/2010/05/25/building-a-better-submission-form/) maybe they will share **Stuffy** with us? :P

Answer (score -3):

I don't think creating such a app in rails would be a great idea.

Using AR, such an app would be creating migrations on the fly - which doesn't sound like a great thing to do.

AFAIK, wufoo uses php.

Comment: Please try to stay on topic when answering questions.

Comment: You don't have to do this creating migrations on the fly (and I am almost certain wufoo is not creating tables for each client), you store the form layout in one or more database tables, or you could even use the postgres to store in a a json field.